# How to prove that a•x = O implies a = 0 or x = O, where a is a real number and x is an element of V (a linear space). O is the zero element of V.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that 0•x = O and a•O = O but how to prove that only these are the cases when we get O when we do a•x (using only the axioms of linear space, and perhaps the uniqueness of O and negative element)?

Comment: multiply by $a^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1: $a = 0$.  Done.

Case 2: $a \neq 0$, so $a^{-1}$ exists.  Consider 
$$  \mathbf{0} = 1 \mathbf{0} = (a^{-1}a)\mathbf{0} = a^{-1}(a \mathbf{0}) = a^{-1} \mathbf{0} = a^{-1} (a \mathbf{x}) = (a^{-1} a) \mathbf{x} = \cdots  \text{.}  $$